# P/invoking the NtQueryVolumeInformationFile function returns 0xC0000003 error

Tags: c#, pinvoke

The C# import code:

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern long NtQueryVolumeInformationFile(IntPtr FileHandle, out IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, IntPtr FsInformation, uint Length, FSINFOCLASS FsInformationClass);
```

The FSINFOCLASS enum:

```
public enum FSINFOCLASS
{
    FileFsVolumeInformation,
    FileFsLabelInformation,
    FileFsSizeInformation,
    FileFsDeviceInformation,
    FileFsAttributeInformation,
    FileFsControlInformation,
    FileFsFullSizeInformation,
    FileFsObjectIdInformation,
    FileFsDriverPathInformation,
    FileFsVolumeFlagsInformation,
    FileFsSectorSizeInformation,
    FileFsDataCopyInformation,
    FileFsMetadataSizeInformation,
    FileFsFullSizeInformationEx,
    FileFsMaximumInformation
}
```

The way it is called:

```
var handlePtr = Win32.CreateFile(@"\\.\c:", Win32.GENERIC_READ, Win32.FILE_SHARE_READ | Win32.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | Win32.FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, Win32.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

if (handlePtr == IntPtr.Zero - 1)
    return 0;

var iosb = new Win32.IO_STATUS_BLOCK();
var buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(273);

var result = Win32.NtQueryVolumeInformationFile(handlePtr, out iosb, buffer, 273,
    Win32.FSINFOCLASS.FileFsVolumeInformation);
 // result=0xC0000003 , should be zero
```

The code runs with the administrative privilege.

The error code's description is: `STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS`

But as far as I can tell, the info class enum is correct.

What am I missing?

Comment: `FileFsVolumeInformation` is `0` here, should be `1`. Don't do this: `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(273);`, *measure* it (`Marshal.SizeOf(...);`) and free it (`Marshal.FreeHGlobal(...);`)

Comment: Thank you, it was so simple, didn't know that it is one based.
And I was aware of that allocation, it was temporary. :-)

Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: In MSDN, it looks like the enumerator's first value is `[dcl.enum]`, since it appears not initialized. It's instead initialized to `1`. This can happen when you use (partially) undocumented functions. Another thing: I don't see the declaration of `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`. If you found around (PInvoke.net for example) this definition: `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]`, **remove Pack = 0**. -- I won't post an answer for this, I consider it a typo. But, of course, you can post it yourself.

Comment: There's also another reason: the structures' marshaling, here, is wildly incomplete (you don't show how you marshal the pointer back to a structure, for example) and the size of the buffer is *undefined* (`273` is not a reference not a measure and I could tell you it should be `256`). So, it's not exactly a good *example* (a consideration that is not *personal*, of course, I just talk about the code).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jimi's comment, I assigned the value 1 to the enum member FileFsVolumeInformation and that fixed that error.

However it needed more fixes to fully work. The complete working code for the interop imports follows:

```
 [DllImport("ntdll.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern long NtQueryVolumeInformationFile(IntPtr FileHandle, out IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, IntPtr FsInformation,
            uint Length, FSINFOCLASS FsInformationClass);
```

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
        public struct FILE_FS_VOLUME_INFORMATION
        {
            public long VolumeCreationTime;
            public uint VolumeSerialNumber;
            public uint VolumeLabelLength;
            public bool SupportsObjects;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1)]
            public string VolumeLabel;
        }
```

```
   public enum FSINFOCLASS
        {
            FileFsVolumeInformation = 1,
            FileFsLabelInformation,
            FileFsSizeInformation,
            FileFsDeviceInformation,
            FileFsAttributeInformation,
            FileFsControlInformation,
            FileFsFullSizeInformation,
            FileFsObjectIdInformation,
            FileFsDriverPathInformation,
            FileFsVolumeFlagsInformation,
            FileFsSectorSizeInformation,
            FileFsDataCopyInformation,
            FileFsMetadataSizeInformation,
            FileFsFullSizeInformationEx,
            FileFsMaximumInformation
        }
```

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
        public struct IO_STATUS_BLOCK
        {
            public uint status;
            public IntPtr information;
        }
```

```
 public uint GetVolumeSerialNumber(string volumePath)
        {
            var handlePtr = Win32.CreateFile($@"\\.\{volumePath.TrimEnd('\\')}", Win32.GENERIC_READ, Win32.FILE_SHARE_READ | Win32.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | Win32.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                0, Win32.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

            if (handlePtr == IntPtr.Zero - 1)
                return 0;

            var iosb = new Win32.IO_STATUS_BLOCK();
            var fsInfo = new Win32.FILE_FS_VOLUME_INFORMATION();
            var bufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(fsInfo) + 32; //32 =maximum ntfs volume label length
            var buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);

            var result = Win32.NtQueryVolumeInformationFile(handlePtr, out iosb, buffer, (uint)bufferSize,
                Win32.FSINFOCLASS.FileFsVolumeInformation);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
                Win32.CloseHandle(handlePtr);
                return 0;
            }

            fsInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Win32.FILE_FS_VOLUME_INFORMATION>(buffer);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
            return fsInfo.VolumeSerialNumber;
        }
```